# POST with Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit

I am creating a simple log-in/register app, consuming predefined JSON-structured data. So far I have created the GET endpoint (using retrofit)

```
public interface RetrofitGet {
@GET("----")
Call<User> getUserDetails();
```

}

EDIT: the POST endPoint:

```
@POST("----")
Call<User> postUserDetails();
```

Then I have a method, taking the entered JSON-like data and set the data as text of 2 of the fields:

```
private void getUser() {
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(url)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    RetrofitGet service = retrofit.create(RetrofitGet.class);

    Call<User> call = service.getUserDetails();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<User> response, Retrofit retrofit) {

            try {

                input_email.setText(response.body().getEmail());
                input_pass.setText(response.body().getPassword());


            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("onResponse", "There is an error");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            Log.d("onFailure", t.toString());
        }


    });
```

What I am trying to do now is to define the POST endpoint, in order to be able the data to be generated from the app (to be taken from the register form), posted on the server, and then handled in the login.

EDIT: 
The method, consuming the POST endpoint so far:

```
private void postUser() {
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(url)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    RetrofitPost service = retrofit.create(RetrofitPost.class);


    Call<User> call = service.postUserDetails();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<User> response, Retrofit retrofit) {

            try {
                emailRegister.getText().toString();
                passRegister.getText().toString();


            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("onResponse", "There is an error");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

So, I have the data, entered by the user on Register, but I don't see it stored in the server and cannot handle it in the Login part.

Any help would be appreciated, 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
@POST("----")
Call<CommonBean> comment(@Body PostComment comment);
```

and the PostComment:

```
public class PostComment {
    private int  pcOrdersId;
    private int   pcStar;
    private String pcComment;
     public PostComment(int pcOrdersId, int pcStar, String pcComment) {
        this.pcOrdersId = pcOrdersId;
        this.pcStar = pcStar;
        this.pcComment = pcComment;
    }
}
```

others on different with 'GET'

Comment: Thanks! What parameters do I provide then when instantiating a Call?  Call<User> call = service.comment(....)

Comment: service.comment(new PostComment(......)), and the data is from your json